# How to download pdf of current page using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a web page in react project that I created, on a button click in that page I should convert the page to pdf and download it. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to do, use a third party npm module like html-pdf

Or even better, use puppeteer directly :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')    
  
async function printPDF(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });
 
  await browser.close();
  return pdf
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can the print pdf be called just like a normal method call from button click event?